# Drawing shapes in a panel

Tags: c#, winforms

hope you can help me. I have to draw some shapes into a panel like a ellipse, circle, square etc.. this is my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnForm.BackColor = Color.White;
    Graphics g = pnForm.CreateGraphics();
    HatchBrush hb = new HatchBrush(HatchStyle.BackwardDiagonal, Color.Black, Color.White);

    if (rbQuadrat.Checked == true)
    {
       g.FillRectangle(hb, 10, 10, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

I set radiobuttons to choose between the shapes, but when I check the square, nothing appears in the panel. I tried various parameters like pnForm.ClientRectangle.Width/Height, other number values etc but nothing worked for me.

PS. It's not the "pnForm.Backcolor = Color.White", I tested it without this code and it doens't work either.

EDIT: I deleted the if clause and now it's working. Let you know when I found my mistake.

Comment: `if (rbQuadrat.Checked == true)` - Nice gem ;-)

Comment: don't forget to dispose graphics and brush objects (with `Dispose` or by `using`). You will get WinAPI resources leak problem otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the name of the method, your code is invoked only once on form load. Windows Forms/GDI is a stateless drawing architecture. It does not know that it should repaint the application if the checkbox's value changes.

Instead do something like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6311024/351836) and make sure to `Invalidate()` the panel you are rendering into whenever the state of your checkbox changes.

Comment: I edited my code and created a paint instead of an load event but same effect as before, nothing happenes when I click on the specific radio button.

Comment: @user3405917: Show your modified code and make sure to call `Invalidate()` when the state changes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `Form_Load` event, you should code the `radioButton_CheckedChanged`. So, if you can handle right some `if` statements, you can draw rectangles, squares and so on when this event is fired.
For instance:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender, e) {
  if(radioButton1.Checked) {
      pnForm.Invalidate(); // or pnForm.Refresh();
      //Draw shape1
  }
}
private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(sender, e) {
  if(radioButton2.Checked) {
     pnForm.Invalidate(); // or pnForm.Refresh();
     //Draw shape2
  }
}
```

and so on.
Hope this helps.